# Reset UIKeyboard State

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have a UITextView which the keyboard enters values into. However, if you clear the text value (i.e uitextview.text = @""), the keyboard's state does not reset to the lowercase alphabet keyboard.

That is, if I was in the middle of typing "hello.." and the textview gets cleared, the keyboard still shows the symbols, rather than back to the alphabetical letters.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out

```
[textview resignFirstResponder]
```

immediately followed by

```
[textview becomeFirstResponder]
```

does the trick. It does seem a little "hacky" though, but with Apple not providing any direct access to the keyboard, it seems that this is the only way.